# How to get last inserted item synchronized

Tags: c#

I try to get last inserted Item on DB, that related with a Web API.
I have a code to show all item, and it works, but how to get the last inserted items synchronized with the Web API, that's my problem.
this my code

```
class Program
{
    static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:1032");
        GetAllItemMongoDB();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static async void GetAllItemMongoDB()
    {
        var jsonResponse = await client.GetStringAsync("api/Symboles");

        var SymboleList = await JsonConvert.DeserializeObjectAsync<List<Symbole>>(jsonResponse);
        foreach (var p in SymboleList)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", p.SymboleID, p.Name, p.Price);
        }
    }
}
```

The idea is the console app listen to the Web API and when the ID incremented will show the last inserted items, Exemple:
if the database had :

1 item1 price1

2 item2 price2

3 item3 price3

and I inserted item4, the app shows "4 item4 price4"

thnx to #JᴀʏMᴇᴇ, I try this code to show last inserted item continuously. But nothing to show (I am already add data in the database)

```
class Program
{
    static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:1032");
        GetAllItemMongoDB().Wait();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static async Task GetAllItemMongoDB()
    {
        var jsonResponse = await client.GetStringAsync("api/Symboles");

        var SymboleList = await JsonConvert.DeserializeObjectAsync<List<Symbole>>(jsonResponse);

        var mosRecentlyInserted = SymboleList.OrderByDescending(o => o.SymboleID).First();

        while (true)
        {
            var newRecentlyInserted = SymboleList.OrderByDescending(o => o.SymboleID).First();
            if (newRecentlyInserted.SymboleID > mosRecentlyInserted.SymboleID)
            {
                mosRecentlyInserted.SymboleID = newRecentlyInserted.SymboleID;
                foreach (var p in SymboleList)
                {
                    if(newRecentlyInserted.SymboleID >= p.SymboleID)
                        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", p.SymboleID, p.Name, p.Price);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is becoming massively verbose, to be honest. The logic's all a bit mixed up.

Comment: so what can be true?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the item with the highest id using linq like:

`var mostRecentlyInserted = SymboleList.OrderByDescending(o => o.Id).First();`

**Assumptions:**

You have added the `System.Linq` namespace.

Your property is called `Id`.